How to apply a grease pencil effect into a scene in three.js

this is how it looks when rendering in three.js and I would like to add a grease pencil kind of thing depending on the view of the camera.
This is what I expected, the result proccessed in blender.

My question is, is there a way to do this effect I did in blender inside three.js or if it's even possible?

I think you mean grease pencil..... anyway, search for a toon shader

This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

@karskunz did you solve the issue? If so, can you post the solution?

@adelriosantiago https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshToonMaterial
